# An exact sequence which is not split

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, exact-sequence

Assume $R$ is an integral domain and $I$ is a non-zero proper ideal in R. Prove that the exact sequence

$$0 \rightarrow I \rightarrow R \rightarrow R/I \rightarrow 0$$

is not split, where the first map is inclusion and the second one is the canonical projection.

On the contrary, suppose that the sequence is split. So, there exists a map $\psi$ such that $\psi \circ i = 1_I$. Now, since $I$ is proper there exists an $x$ in $R$ such that it's not the image of any element in $I$ under inclusion. So, $\psi(x)$ is in $I$ and so it is in the kernel of the canonical projection. Then I don't know where to go with this. Also, we can alternatively use the fact that $R$ is a direct sum of $I$ and $R/I$ and try to get a contradiction. The fact that $R$ is both free and projective is the only properties that comes to my mind. But then I don't think this leads to something useful. I guess I should keep going with the former idea to get it done. So, perhaps I should consider the inverse of projection to proceed further. Then since $\psi(x)$ is already in the kernel, we reach an stalemate. I then have got to  consider the image of $x$ in $R/I$ and then take the inverse of it and try to relate it to $\psi(x)$.

Comment: I've added the assumption that $I$ must be non-zero. Otherwise the sequence clearly splits.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg precisely, thanks!

Comment: Use the following two hints: 1) The only idempotents in an integral domain are $0$ and $1$. 2) The exact sequence $0 \to I \to R \to R/I \to 0$ (for any commutative ring $R$ and any ideal $I$ of $R$) splits if and only if $I=eR$ for some idempotent $e$ in $R$.

Comment: Notation: You can use `\circ` for the composition symbol.

Comment: @SammyBlack nice! I was looking for that.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang How do you prove the other direction of 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prove that every non-trivial submodule $M$ of the $R$-module $R$ satisfies $\mathrm{Ann}_R(M)=0$, here you will simply use that $R$ is an integral domain. But $\mathrm{Ann}_R(R/I) = I$.

Here, $\mathrm{Ann}_R(M) := \{r \in R : r M = 0 \}$.